# Content pulled in via jQuery AJAX is not associating with previous functions

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the jQuery `.load()` function to pull in data to populate a div with. The content I'm pulling in has CSS selectors that should match up with jQuery click functions I've written. However, when I load in the data, although the correct CSS selectors are there, when I click on areas that should invoke a response from jQuery, nothing happens.

Do I need to do some sort of reload?

Here's the code I've got for the jQuery AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// AJAX functionality for drupal nodes
$(".ajax_node").click(function() {
    var ajax_src = $(this).attr("href"); // we're gonna load the href

    // empty target div and load in content
    // the space in the string before the #id is necessary
    $("#ajax_area").empty().load(ajax_src + " #ajax_wrapper");
    return false; // stops the link from following through
});

// General AJAX functionality
$(".ajax").click(function() {
    var ajax_src = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#ajax_area").empty().load(ajax_src);
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this format:

```
$(".ajax_node").click(function() {
```

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for current and future elements, like this:

```
$(".ajax_node").live('click', function() {
```

The why: `.live()` listens for the event to bubble up at the DOM root, or `document`.  It's a single event handler bound there...it doesn't matter when an element was added, they all bubble the `click` the same, when the click gets there: it checks the selector, if it matches it runs the handler.

Why your current method doesn't work: It's finding all the elements that match that selector **at that time** and binding the handler...new elements aren't there, so don't get that handler.  You have 2 options to solve this, either use `.live()` which works in a different way, as described above, or re-bind the handler to that selector in the content of the request, like this:

```
function callback(data) { //your success callback, e.g. .load(url, callback)
  $(".ajax_node", data).click(myFunction);
}
```

In your case, I think `.live()` is much easier, you generally do the second with widgets and such, not strictly event handlers...but whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 4):

It's not working because you're essentially recreating the elements when you pull them in via `load` and you need to rebind the event handlers. I recommend using [jQuery's live binding](http://api.jquery.com/live/)